# Ubuntu Server installation command mode - cfdisk command not found

Tags: raid

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 10.04 server with LVM+RAID.
However, when I use cfdisk command to create new partition, I received the message: /bin/sh: cfdisk: not found.
Please advise me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the normal menu driven installer screens to partition the drive.  If you switch to the other tty, the environment is bare bones minimal and does not include cfdisk ( but iirc, it does have fdisk ).

Comment: Suckingly it doesn't. 12.04 alternate doesn't seem to have any command line fdisk at all ({c,s,}fdisk).

Answer (score 0):

Normally this command is located in **/sbin**. Please try to run it as **sudo /sbin/cfdisk**.

Comment: `which` or `whereis` can also track it down

Comment: "Normally" PATH includes /sbin — just FYI.